# HTTP 404 with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I've trouble solving a 404 error:

Default Route in Global.asax.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Default", 
       "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

VideoController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(int id)
{
   try
   {
     return Json(new
     {
       ID = "0"
     });
   }
   catch
   {
     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(418, "I'm a teapot");
   }
}
```

ActionLink in my view, Create.cshtml:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("GoSave", "Save", "Video", new { id = 1 },
        new AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "Error", OnSuccess = "Saved", 
                          HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

The url of the actionlink is rendered as expected: /Video/Save/1

When I click on the link I get an 404.

What is it I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I bet you are missing a `script` inclusion:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will unobtrusively AJAXify the `Ajax.ActionLink` generated result and perform a POST request instead of the default GET one. You are getting 404 because you haven't included this script and so a GET request is sent and there is no Save action on Video controller capable of receiving a GET request.

If you have used [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) you would immediately have seen this: that the browser is simply redirecting and sending a GET request instead of the expected Ajax POST request.

Comment: Tnx again! ;) Firebug isn't compatible with FF4, yet.

Comment: @Andrew Flierman, then use older version. I mean, developing a web application without FireBug is like trying to play football without a ball (not even thinking about an AJAX enabled web application). In both cases the result will be the same => failure to achieve the initial goal :-)

Comment: @Andrew Flierman: Firebug has been compatible with FF4 even when in beta. There was Firebug 1.7 beta as well and they played together as expected.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, did you not know about [rfc2324](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2324)?

Comment: @zzzzBov, lol, no I didn't. Nice one. Thanks for pointing it out. I have removed my wrong remark from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Darin's answer...

Add this NuGet package, which "unobtrusively sets up jQuery Ajax."

[image]

All this package does is install the necessary scripts.

[image]

Next, do what Darin says or, equivalently, add:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

to _Layout.cshtml